# The maximum record length exceeded?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, export

I downloaded some census tract data which are stored in .gdb. I am able to open them in ArcGIS as shpfiles. I selected some tracts and tried to export them into another folder. But I kept getting this error: "Error exporting data. The maximum record length has been exceeded". Is this because the attribute table has too many columns? What is the solution?

Comment: How can you open a file geodatabase as a shapefile?

Answer (score 7):

Shapefiles, dependent as they are on dBaseIII-ish features, have all the [limitations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005600000013000000#GUID-A10ADA3B-0988-4AB1-9EBA-AD704F77B4A2) of dBaseIII:

- Ten character field names
- 254-character field width
- 255 fields/table
- 4000-byte record limit
- Limited to day resolution in timestamp fields
- No support for numeric nulls
- No support for BLOB, CLOB, NSTRING, or NCLOB

In your particular case, you seem to have hit the 4k record limit (which could be breached in as few as 16 Text fields).

The solution to shapefile limitations is not using shapefiles.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the data from all columns, you can turn off the fields that you don't need and then export them. Those fields won't be part of the export and thus you won't exceed the record limit.

Comment: How do you "turn off" columns?

Comment: right click column header and select turn off